# Java, Spring : Setting timeout for a method so the code returns to method end.

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I have certain methods which do task of creating previews of files like doc, docx, ppt, etc. Now, the entry point for all these methods is a single method. I am using multiple technologies like docx4j, apache-poi, etc.

Even after a lot of tests, sometimes the conversion fails, which is not a problem, but the request from front-end is not finished and the tab eventually dies. WHat I would like to do is to give a timeout for the entry-point method, so if the conversion doesn't succeed in 20 seconds, then the conversion process is  halted.

IS there anything similar I can do in Spring-MVC.

Code :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GroupAttachmentsServiceImpl implements GroupAttachmentsService {

  @Override
    public boolean addAttachment(byte[] bytes, String fileName){
    // Attachment to file-system persistence code
  try {

                     attachment.setImageThumbnail(createFilePreviewForFiles(fileName, bytes));
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }

}
```

// Below is entry-point method for which I would like to set some timeout

```
 @Override
    public String createFilePreviewForFiles(String fileName, byte[] fileBytes) {

        try {
            if (!(fileBytes == null)) {

                String targetLocation = zipLocation + String.valueOf(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));

                FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(targetLocation), fileBytes);

                String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length()).toLowerCase();

                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("pdf")) {
                    return (createPdfPreview(targetLocation));
                }

                if ((extension.toLowerCase().equals("pptx"))) {
                    return (createPPtxPreview(targetLocation));
                }

                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("ppt")) {
                    //  return createPptPreview(targetLocation);
                    return null;
                }

                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("doc")) {
                    return createDocToPDfAndThenToImage(targetLocation);
                    // return null;
                }

                if ((extension.toLowerCase().equals("docx"))) {
                    return (createDocxToPdfAndThenToImage(targetLocation));
                }


                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("xls")) {
                    return (convertXlsToPDfAndToImage(targetLocation));
                }

                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("xlsx")) {
                    return (convertXlsxToPdfAndToImage(targetLocation));
                }

                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("png")) {
                    return createThumbNailWithoutPathAndReturnImage(fileBytes);
                }


                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("jpg")) {
                    return createThumbNailWithoutPathAndReturnImage(fileBytes);
                }


                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("jpeg")) {
                    return createThumbNailWithoutPathAndReturnImage(fileBytes);
                }

                if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("mp4")) {
                    return createPreviewForVideos(targetLocation);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            return "";
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why not to specify web request timeout?

Comment: @Argb32 : Because the web request comprises of adding attachment and creating previews is only part of it.. i dont wamt the user to upload attachment again, i just want to skip previews in casw of failure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the ways to implement your requirement is to call your method asynchronously.  The method will need to return `Future` or `CompletableFuture` (if you are using Java 8).

So you will have a method annotated with `@Async` (you need to enable async with `@EnableAsync` in your config):

```
@Async
   CompletableFuture<Void> createDocxToPdfAndThenToImage(String targetLocation)
```

and your call could be  (there are a lot of other options with `CompletableFuture`):

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future= createDocxToPdfAndThenToImage(targetLocation);
   future.get( 10, SECONDS)
```

This will throw a `TimeoutException` if method takes longer than the timeout value.

Since in your case you need to return `String`, you can do

```
        @Async
       CompletableFuture<String> createDocxToPdfAndThenToImage(String targetLocation)  ....

       CompletableFuture<String> future=createDocxToPdfAndThenToImage(targetLocation);
       return future.get( 10, SECONDS);
```

Comment: How can I return Completeable future with a String? I am returning a String currently as the image preview is a String format. And as you can see there are multiple methods all returning String. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer. You also need to put @Async methods in the class different from the calling class

Comment: Hi, THank you for the update, but I guess you are missing the point, the method createDocXToPdfAndThenToImage returns a String, not a CompleteTableFuture object. That's what I asked how to return that instead of String, you have described how to call this method, but not how to return a CompleteableFuture object instead of String.

Comment: Also, rather than modifying 10 different methods, isn't there anything I can do for the entrypoint method(createFilePreviewForFiles()). The only reason I gave that  method was to have a centralized control. A bit more details would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you could create a wrapper method. But I trust, you can figure it out yourself